# Trouble with Inheritence

Tags: inheritance

I have a class called Polygon with a subclass (if that's the right term) called Triangle. Triangle has a function called circumcenter(). Polygon has no such function.

I have a vector of polygons. I would like call for one of these polygons, which I know to be a triangle, the circumcenter function. Upon calling Polygons[0].circumcenter() I arrive at the error "class Polygon has no member named 'circumcenter'", I assume because the program does not know the Polygon is a triangle.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: like what @OliCharlesworth said add a tag for the code you are using also you probably need to cast the object a triangle first.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages will let you cast to the right type.
e.g. java

```
if (polygons[0] instanceof Triangle) {
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle)polygons[0];
    triangle.circumcenter();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you do it one line with `((Triangle)polygons[0]).circumcenter()` ?

Comment: You could, but if OP doesn't know about casting, then I think KISS applies ;-)

Comment: This is true. Sometimes I forget about the philosophy of KISS :P

Comment: Good old KISS (insert flying fire breathing blood spitting demon playing the bass here...)